# POST request in WP8 app

Tags: vb.net, http, xaml, post, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a VB.NET app for Windows Phone 8 and I'm currently looking for a solution to send a POST request to a page, and to get the response (simply knowing the page content).
I searched on several forums but none of them helped me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before u have to download this NuGet package HttpClient for Windows Phone and try this code:
`var httpClient = new HttpClient();`
`var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.google.com/");`
`var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);`
`var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

This will help you.

And u have to use in async method try this. 
`Async Function AccessTheWebAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    Dim getStringTask As Task(Of String) = client.GetStringAsync("http://google.com")
    Dim urlContents As String = Await getStringTask
    Return urlContents.Length
End Function`

Comment: OK, i converted your code to VB.NET, but it did not work :(
I get this error message : `await' can only be used in a method marked with the 'async' modifier`

Comment: still the same problem... I added your function to my code, but the same error occurs at the same place...
You can see my code here : http://pastebin.com/ErMfKFZ2

Comment: well then look at that post on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx